# Why monodevelop is not showing any error?

Tags: c#, configuration, monodevelop

I have just installed Monodevelop to use it in conjunction with unity. When I use it and I assigning string to typed int, I am expecting an error.

Why monodevelop is not showing any error? Like red line under  `MyInt = "qaefef";`

Am I missing a configuration somewhere?

[image]

Comment: There's also the missing `;` on `private int MyInt`

Comment: Why MonoDevelop? https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/01/05/discontinuing-support-for-monodevelop-unity-starting-in-unity-2018-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing your .sln file, according to [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1570497/monodevelop-intellisense-not-working-unity-552.html) on Unity Answers, or you can try reinstalling the .NET framework according to this answer [on there](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1366884/view.html).

Regardless, MonoDevelop has been abandoned by Unity for a long time. You should be using Visual Studio ([read this announcement](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/01/05/discontinuing-support-for-monodevelop-unity-starting-in-unity-2018-1/)).